# Line Chart in Excel or Tableau having markers on that line chart with another column other than Data in X or Y axis

Tags: excel, graph, data-visualization, tableau-api, linechart

I have three columns GDP, TFP and Country. I want to plot a Line chart where TFP will be on Y-Axis and GDP on X-axis. And a line chart having markers on that representing the Country. The markers of corresponding country appear on line (Line Chart) where GDP and TFP intersect. Is there any way to plot either through Excel or Tableau?

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking. Can you show a mock up of the chart with labels you expect? Also some data to reflect the mocked up chart?

Comment: I want the country names on the line as markers while rest of the columns TFP on Yaxis and GDP on X-Axis, I am unable to show the country names on the line.

Comment: Have you tried adding a Label to the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put GDP and TFP under Rows and Columns, and add the Country field to Details and Label in the Marks card. Attaching an image for reference- Countries PQR and MNO both have an intersection of GDP and TFP.
[Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ1To.png)